# How do I calculate the voltage of a resistor after the fuse has been blown?

Tags: voltage, resistors, fuses

For example, theres a battery of 12v in a seris with R1 (resitor 1) of 49kilo ohms, then there's a blown fuse of 90uA, next is  R2 of 11kilo ohms, then there's R3 of 60 kilo ohms.

How do i calculate Voltage of R1 when the blown fuse has infinite resistence?

Comment: A 90 microampere fuse? Really?

Comment: It's for testing

Comment: What I was wondering was, where do you get a 90 microampere fuse? Can you give a manufacturer and part number?

Comment: Multisim is the software that allows me to do that

Comment: Won't Multisim also tell you the voltage across R1? Is this some kind of homework problem?

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to know how to calculate it myself

Comment: Zero volts, I would guess.  Fuse is blown => it's an open circuit.  If there are resistors in series with the fuse, there's no current flowing through them.  V = I*R = 0*R = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First ask yourself, what is the current through the resistor?

Since the resistor is in series with a blown fuse, the current is 0.

Now Ohm's law is V=IR. So the voltage across the resistor is 0 (because R is not infinite).

Comment: If the fuse wasn't blown, the current would be It = 0.1mA

Comment: That doesn't affect what the current is when the fuse *is* blown. So it doesn't affect what the voltages are when the fuse is blown.

Comment: So you're saying the voltage of R1 will remain 4.9V even when the fuse is blown?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi: No - all the voltage will be across the blown fue.  There will be no voltage across any of the resistors, as there is no current flowing in the circuit.

Comment: @PeterBennett Ok, so R1 has 0V after blown fuse. Is it still V=IR, then V= 0.1*49? Please clarify which formula to use

Comment: After the fuse is blown, I is 0. V = I R = 0 x R. Zero times anything is zero. So V = 0.